# Authenticate facebook users without facebook login

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to play a little bit around with the Facebook API and have read through their webpages (developers.facebook.com) and watched their video tutorials. But I don't think they have been good at explaining stuff to me. Could someone redirect me to a webpage or explain how I can authenticate a user and get his permission to do certain things (for example read his home feed) without using the facebook login plugin for my website login-process?

I want the user to use my login-function to log on to the page, and then choose Facebook from a drop-down menu. Then it will take them to a /facebook.php site which authenticates them and they grant some permissions.

How do I do this? What kind of code do I have to include to my website?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Are you using the js or the php api? You can certainly wait to fire the Fb.login() in js until whenever you want. Also, FB api docs aren't the best -- they get outdated quite fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating Facebook User without using Login Button

JavaScript : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

PHP : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/